# XSL Transformation issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am trying to transform an XML file with XSL to another XML that is going to have a format like this:

Input file:

```
<mediaRecords>
    <media mediaName="ID Generator_000005" mediaType="Video" origSOM="00:00:00:00" creationTime="2016-02-12T10:16:48" modifiedTime="2016-02-12T10:16:48">
        <properties>
            <classifications>
                <classification classification="MediaType" category="[Unknown]"/>
                <classification classification="MediaType2" category="[Unknown]"/>
                <classification classification="QA Status" category="[Unknown]"/>
            </classifications>
            <markups/>
        </properties>
        <mediaInstances>
            <mediaInstance mediaSetName="Ingest Device" version="1" versionHint="Initial" duration="00:00:00:00" position="00:00:00:00" directory="demoDevice/mediaDir" filename="ID Generator_000005" creationStartTime="2016-02-12T10:16:48:00" creationEndTime="2016-02-12T10:16:48:00" sourceURL="[Unknown]" destURL="[Unknown]">
                <properties/>
            </mediaInstance>
        </mediaInstances>
    </media>
</mediaRecords>
```

XLS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="Material">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications">
   <xsl:element name="classification" >
      <xsl:attribute name="test">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications/classification/@classification" />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element> 
   <xsl:element name="classification" >
      <xsl:attribute name="test2">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications/classification/@classification" />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   <xsl:element name="media" >
      <xsl:attribute name="MatID">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="media" >
    <xsl:attribute name="startTime">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@origSOM" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="media" >
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@mediaType" />
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   <xsl:element name="xxx" >
    <xsl:attribute name="marios">
         <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/mediaInstances/mediaInstance/@mediaSetName" />
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired XML output:

```
<Material>
 <classification test="MediaType" />
 <classification test2="MediaType" />
 <media MatID="ID Generator_000005" />
 <media startTime="00:00:00:00" />
 <Track>
  <media type="Video" />
  <xxx marios="Ingest Device" />
 </Track>
</Material>
<Request>
<classification test="MediaType" />
<media type="Video" />
<xxx marios="Ingest Device" />
</Request>
```

In my code I have **2 problems.**

First of all, I cannot nest the `<Track>` and `<Request>` as the desired output.

The second one is that in my original XML, I have classification 3 times and I want for example to output only the second or the 3rd one. How I can choose which one I can output?

Comment: Please explain the expected output in a more detailed way. You can select positions of elements with e.g. `classification[2]`. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

Comment: let me elaborate a bit @uL1 . In the Desired XML you can see the Material class and inside it there is one Track class if I can say so. My question is how I can export it like that? Moreover, I have one more class called Request. Currently in my XSL code, I can output only one class (Material) and I cannot create nested and more than one classes.

Comment: Moreover, the classification[2] is not giving me the "MediaType2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, the required output could be achieved much more simply using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/mediaRecords">
    <Material>
        <classification test="{media/properties/classifications/classification[2]/@classification}" />
        <media MatID="{media/@mediaName}" />
        <media startTime="{media/@origSOM}" />
        <Track>
            <media type="{media/@mediaType}" />
            <xxx marios="{media/mediaInstances/mediaInstance/@mediaSetName}" />
        </Track>
    </Material>
    <Request>
        <classification test="MediaType" />
        <media type="{media/@mediaType}" />
        <xxx marios="{media/mediaInstances/mediaInstance/@mediaSetName}" />
    </Request>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This selects the second `classification` and returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Material>
   <classification test="MediaType2"/>
   <media MatID="ID Generator_000005"/>
   <media startTime="00:00:00:00"/>
   <Track>
      <media type="Video"/>
      <xxx marios="Ingest Device"/>
   </Track>
</Material>
<Request>
   <classification test="MediaType"/>
   <media type="Video"/>
   <xxx marios="Ingest Device"/>
</Request>
```

Note that this assumes there is only one media record in the input.

Note also that the output is not well-formed XML, as it does not have a single root element.

Comment: thanks for your answer @michael.hor257k but I need an XSL format. When I am trying to see the output of your code I get an error.

Comment: @Marios I don't know what you mean by "an XSL format". The above is a valid XSLT 1.0  styleheet. When I apply it to your example input, I get the result shown.

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k . The online page I was using had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can select n-th element by `[n]` counting from 1.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Material">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <Request>
          <xsl:element name="classification" >
            <xsl:attribute name="test">
              <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications/classification[1]/@classification" />
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:call-template name="mediaXXX" />
        </Request>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications">
        <xsl:element name="classification" >
          <xsl:attribute name="test">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications/classification[2]/@classification" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="classification" >
          <xsl:attribute name="test2">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/properties/classifications/classification[3]/@classification" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="media" >
          <xsl:attribute name="MatID">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="media" >
          <xsl:attribute name="startTime">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@origSOM" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <Track>
          <xsl:call-template name="mediaXXX" />
        </Track>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template name="mediaXXX">
        <xsl:element name="media" >
          <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@mediaType" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="xxx" >
          <xsl:attribute name="marios">
            <xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/mediaInstances/mediaInstance/@mediaSetName" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am using this parser and I also get an error with your code : http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Comment: and again the classification is not working. I get always the first one with your code. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I' ve put your input xml and my xslt into this http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.V_uz8Mm3Gb8
and get correct output.

Comment: you are right. Probably mine is not working ok. One more question. If my desired xml would have the above format: <MatID>ID Generator_000005</MatID> what I have to change in your code?

Comment: The simplest one is to put 
<MatID><xsl:value-of select="/mediaRecords/media/@mediaName" /></MatID> insead of current block which produce 'media' element with 'MatID' attribute.